# Given the following set of LISP primitives, is it possible to extend the eval function to evaluate defmacro?

Tags: functional-programming

In this [paper](http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/pub/misc/micromanualLISP.pdf) McCarthy sets out the following primitives: `QUOTE`, `CAR`, `CDR`, `CONS`, `EQUAL`, `ATOM`, `COND`, `LAMBDA` and `LABEL`.

He then sets up the following abbreviations: `T`, `NIL`, `DEFUN`, `NULL`, `CADR`, `LIST`, `AND`, `ALT`, and `SUBST`.

He rounds it up with an incredible definition of the `EVAL` function used in the reader.

Given the above set of LISP primitives, is it possible to extend the `EVAL` function to evaluate defmacro?

Comment: The book: Lisp in Small Pieces by Christian Queinnec presents an implementation of macros in Scheme that might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in fact it's quite similar to evaluating `DEFUN`. Of course, in the paper `EVAL` has no rule for evaluating `DEFUN`, since it's treated as an abbreviation. From the definition of `DEFMACRO` in emacs LISP ([link](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Defining-Macros.html)):

> Special Form: defmacro name argument-list body-forms...
>
> defmacro defines the symbol name as a macro that looks like this:
>
> `(macro lambda argument-list . body-forms)`

It's easier if we ignore the name of the macro and treat that as an abbreviation. Then we have simply to create the list `(macro lambda argument-list . body-forms)` and set `name` to be shorthand for that list, the same way a `(defun name (arguments) (body))` sets `name` as a shorthand for `(lambda (arguments) (body))`. As for evaluating a macro, that is also easy --- just pass the function inside the macro your arguments, but WITHOUT evaluating them first.

Comment: Are you saying that defmacro would need to be implemented by both a modification to eval and a new primitve? (Being similar to defun)

Comment: The name binding part would need a new primitive, or however it's actually handled in eval --- since the paper treats the name-binding part of defun as an abbreviation. AFAIK, an interpreter keeps a lookup table with variable bindings, and defun etc. will add an entry to that table saying "this variable is now bound to this function". So, if you ignore the name-binding part, you need only modify eval.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683388/given-the-the-following-lisp-eval-function-what-is-required-to-add-defmacro) shows macro expansion as a 'code template' to solve this problem.

Comment: link is not a good answer. Could you please expand this? Thanks.